# Qt system tray icon disappears when menu opened on OSX 10.10

Tags: c++, macos, qt, system-tray

I have simple qt code:

```
sticon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
QIcon icon(":/music.png");
sticon->setIcon(icon);

QMenu* stmenu = new QMenu(NULL);
action = new QAction("test",NULL);
stmenu->addAction(action);
sticon->setContextMenu(stmenu);
sticon->show();
connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(clickText()));
```

And when I click on the menu, I get errors and Tray icon disappears:

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
```

It works on OSX 10.10 + Qt 5.4
What is the problem?

Comment: where does it not work?

Comment: It works, but when I click on menu action "test", icon dissapears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Qt 5.4 bug:

> On Mac OS X 10.9.5, run QSystemTrayIcon example included in the Qt
>   installation. Click on the icon shown on the menu bar to activate the
>   menu. Then click elsewhere to deactiviate it. The icon goes blank on
>   the menu bar. If you click on the blank space again, the icon
>   re-appears.

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-42910?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel